# How can I protect an exposed refrigerant pipe outdoors?

Tags: hvac

I have approx.12 ft. of copper pipe carrying freon laying on top of the ground. Best way to protect it without cutting in two & loosing all freon? (Not enough slack to bury.)

Comment: When was this installed? The installer should have sleeved it. You can buy foam insulation at a big box store, and it is slit down the center. You can slide it over existing pipe and then wrap it and zip tie it to keep water out.

Comment: Sometimes the installer only insulates the suction line this is to prevent condensation on AC systems, it is cheaper but some efficiency is lost. Neoprene sheeting is 1 way that is easy way to wrap linesets. But as others have said there are many methods.

Answer (score 1):

There is now made a product that is called a a/c line set cover.  Google 'line set cover'.  tons of companies will pop up more than happy to sell to you.